# CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform ssm:GetParameter on resource: using @aws-sdk v3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, amazon-javascript-sdk, aws-ssm

I am trying to get parameters in AWS Parameter Store using @aws-sdk v3 with cognito unauthenticated identity pool like this:

```
import { SSMClient, GetParameterCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ssm";
import { fromCognitoIdentityPool } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";

const REGION = 'us-east-1'

const ssm = new SSMClient({
  region: REGION,
  credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
    clientConfig: { region: REGION },
    identityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxx...'
  })
});

const input = {
  Name: '/config'
}

const response = await ssm.send(new GetParameterCommand(param));
```

But I am receiving this message:

> AccessDeniedException: User:
> arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/Cognito_CredentialsUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials
> is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource:
> arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:parameter/config because no session
> policy allows the ssm:GetParameter action

My cognito role is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
            "cognito-sync:*",
            "ssm:GetParameters",
            "ssm:GetParameter"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I talk to aws support and they sad that my role is right, and the problem is in my session policy. But I don't understand what I need to do

Comment: It looks like your user isn't authenticated. So CredentialsUnauth_Role is assumed. Do you let Unauth user to access ssm:GetParameter? I mean is it intentionally? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html is it of any help?